# ASP, HyperLink Open small Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

My site has `Gridview` controls and some of them must have hyperlinks on every record. What I need is that the hyperlink open a new and small window, because i send data from the grids to new window.

This is my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwCajUpd" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                                Font-Size="Smaller" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCajUpd_CadDet" Text="Detalle" runat="server" target="_blank"
                                                NavigateUrl='<%# "Cajas_Detalle.aspx?cliCod=" + Eval("ClienteCodigo").ToString() 
                                                    + "&cajCod=" + Eval("CajaCodigo").ToString() 
                                                    + "&cajNum=" + Eval("CajaNumero").ToString()
                                                    + "&cajCon=" + Eval("CajaContenido").ToString()
                                            %>'/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID = "lblCajUpd_CliCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClienteCodigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COD.CAJA">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID = "lblCajUpd_CajCod" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CajaCodigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NUM">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID = "lblCajUpd_CajNum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CajaNumero") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <!--- more and more data -->
```

I recieve the data in my new window, but I need this new window small and NOT in in a new tab.

Comment: I don't think you can force a hyperlink to open in a window rather than a tab, that's up to the user's browser settings.

Comment: You should be probably using JavaScript to do so if it's for the same page.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you want use hyperlink ,
Use this code instead

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Sample.aspx?id= <%#Eval("UserCourseId") %> ','PrintMe','height=700px,width=500px,scrollbars=1');">SomeText</a>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

Instead of `NavigateUrl` use `OnClick` with javascript function that will open a small new window like the way you want.

```
NavigateUrl="#"        
onClick='<%# "window.open('Cajas_Detalle.aspx?cliCod=" + 
                      Eval("ClienteCodigo") + "&cajCod=" + Eval("CajaCodigo") + 
                      "&cajNum=" + Eval("CajaNumero") + "&cajCon=" + 
                      Eval("CajaContenido")+ 
                      ",'name','height=550, width=790,toolbar=no,
                      directories=no,status=no,
                      menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no'); 
                      return false;%>'
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot aref
I could resolve my problem:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Cajas_Detalle.aspx?cliCod= <%#Eval("ClienteCodigo").ToString() 
                                                + "&cajCod=" + Eval("CajaCodigo").ToString() 
                                                + "&cajNum=" + Eval("CajaNumero").ToString()        
                                                %> ','PrintMe','height=400px,width=800px,scrollbars=1');">Detalle</a>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks 
best regards